# Is type assignability too strict in JavaConstant.Dynamic.ofInvocation()?

Tags: byte-buddy

I've read [Rafael's article](https://mydailyjava.blogspot.com/2018/08/hands-on-constantdynamic-class-file.html) and am now doing awful, terrible things with `JavaConstant.Dynamic`.  Mostly I'm getting a feel for how it works.

As part of these horrid experiments, I am turning an array of non-constant things into an array of `JavaConstant`s.  Then I'm invoking `JavaConstant.Dynamic.ofInvocation(SOME_METHOD_THAT_ACCEPTS_A_VARARGS_OF_THINGS, javaConstantsArray)`.

So, for example, something like this:

```
static final JavaConstant toJavaConstant(final Glorp[] glorps) {
  final JavaConstant[] javaConstants = new JavaConstant[glorps.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < javaConstants.length; i++) {
    javaConstants[i] = toJavaConstant(glorps[i]); // another version of this method that works on scalars
  }
  return JavaConstant.Dynamic.ofInvocation(SOME_METHOD_THAT_ACCEPTS_A_VARARGS_OF_THINGS, javaConstants);
}
```

ByteBuddy is telling me in the `ofInvocation` call that one of the `JavaConstant`s in the varargs array I've passed it is not assignable to the parameter type of the `SOME_METHOD_THAT_ACCEPTS_A_VARARGS_OF_THINGS`.  I can understand this, because strictly speaking a variable arity method accepts an array as its last parameter, and a `JavaConstant` is not an array.  But given that the `SOME_METHOD_THAT_ACCEPTS_A_VARARGS_OF_THINGS` is ultimately resolved via the `MethodHandle` machinery with all of its argument adaptation and spreading tricks, I wonder: is [this proactive assignability check](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/e4ce4af1bab578a7ac3497d07449e50628d050e7/byte-buddy-dep/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/utility/JavaConstant.java#L1636-L1638) "too much"?  Should ByteBuddy take into account the varargs nature of the bootstrap method?  Is there some other way to create an array or a list of an arbitrary number of scalar constants as a constant itself?

Comment: Indeed, it appears that this is too strict of a check.  When I compile a version of ByteBuddy with this check omitted, everything works fine.  I'll file a bug shortly.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/954 to track this.

Comment: I fixed it with https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/pull/955.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this was a bug and it will be fixed in Byte Buddy 1.10.18. Thanks for the patch!